# How do I clear/empty the text in the input field after a download event is finished? -- Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, input, download

I have struggled hours and hours dealing with the text(URL) which is not emptied after a download is complete. The app I'm making now is a video downloader and in the client side, a URL is supposed to be filled in and click on the download button.

Videos are downloaded successfully, but one tiny issue is the URL put into the input field doesn't get cleared after a video is downloaded. The image down below will explains it well:
Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/DL6WldDYi5PE

How do I make it work? I want the filled user input field to be gotten rid of and be completely empty after the process.

This is the corresponding block of code in the server code:

```
app.get('/download', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const url = req.query.url;
        console.log(url);
        const options = {
            quality: '18',
            filter: format => format.container === 'mp4' && format.hasAudio && format.hasVideo, 
        };

        //Fetch Video ID metadata 
        const videoId = await ytdl.getURLVideoID(url);
        console.log("Video ID fetched:", videoId);

        //Set the content dispositon header to trigger download
        res.attachment(`${videoId}.mp4`);

        //Download and pipe the video stream
        const videoStream = ytdl(url, options);
        videoStream.pipe(res);

        videoStream.on('finish', () => {
            console.log("Video is downloaded.");
            res.end();
        });

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send("Internal server error");
    }
});
```

I tried to add an event listener in the client side (EJS) to get the input field wiped out. But didn't work at all. I think it would need some adjustment in the server side to signal the completion of a video download to the client side  each time a video gets downloaded so addEventListener can handle the process (to clear out the filled input field).. Just my humble thought, but very confusing how actually to implement it...

I would really appreciate awesome people that help..

P.S. Sorry if this is a duplicate question, I have searched through all the questions I have ever seen here and tried to find a solution from any other web resources, but failed...

Comment: You need to paste your front-end code into the question. How are you submitting the request for the download, I assume you have a click handler and sending via Axios/fetch? We need that code. Clearing the input is a trivial task once you share that code.

Comment: Thank you for the comment!! Now the problem has been solved, but I really appreciate your attention to this issue and your advice to sharing more comprehensive code in detail. I will keep that in mind! Thank you jQueeny!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anywhere in your current function which removes the input value, thus the input value is still present. Replacing the input value with an empty string should do the trick:

```
 place_Input_Field_Id_Here.value = '';
```

Here is a snippet with the code you've provided with what I am guessing is your input field id `videoId.value = '';`, but feel free to replace this with whatever your actual input field id really is.

```js
app.get('/download', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const url = req.query.url;
        console.log(url);
        const options = {
            quality: '18',
            filter: format => format.container === 'mp4' && format.hasAudio && format.hasVideo, 
        };

        //Fetch Video ID metadata 
        const videoId = await ytdl.getURLVideoID(url);
        console.log("Video ID fetched:", videoId);

        //Set the content dispositon header to trigger download
        res.attachment(`${videoId}.mp4`);

        //Download and pipe the video stream
        const videoStream = ytdl(url, options);
        videoStream.pipe(res);

        videoStream.on('finish', () => {
            console.log("Video is downloaded.");
            res.end();
        });
        
     //clear input value
     videoId.value = '';

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send("Internal server error");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nick! It helped a lot for me to get hinted! The inter crossing server and client side communication was a bit too tricky to me, I have got errors all the time at every single attempt. But with your hint, I decided to go an easier way just in the client side with no server side involved and then I managed to get it working by setting a setTimeout in the client side and get the video.value = ''; 

Thank you so much!!! Your help was an awesome hint to get this one solved!!! :) :)